# creating a timer counter - Python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using Django for a project, and I have the following method:

```
TIMEOUT = 10 # defines the timeout in sec
def read_cluster_log(proc, cluster):
    logs = ""
    while True:
       line = proc.stdout.readline()
       if not line:
          break
       logging.info(line)
       # here I need to add a buffer:
       # if the 'counter' is equal to 10 sec
       # append logs to the database and reset the timer to 0
       # else, keep appending.  
       logs += line
    cluster_log = ClusterLog(cluster=cluster, log=logs)
    cluster_log.save()
    return cluster_log
```

As of now this function captures the entire output, and saves it to the database. `log` is a `BinaryField`. What I needed to do is to set up a timer, which runs from 0 to `TIMEOUT`, and then appends the current log to the `log` field for that `cluster`. The timer is reset to 0, and it continues until the program ends.
The idea here is to make the output available from a website, when the user creates a `Hadoop` Cluster. However, that part is being a little bit trickier. Could someone help me out? 
The database this `Django` application is running on is `MySQL`

Comment: I am not sure but I think you need to use something like Celery(http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) here

Answer (score 0):

Try `sleep(n)` which would sleep for n seconds.

```
import time

TIMEOUT = 10 # defines the timeout in sec
def read_cluster_log(proc, cluster):
    logs = ""
    while True:
       line = proc.stdout.readline()
       if not line:
          break
       logging.info(line)

       #changed here
       time.sleep(TIMEOUT) #sleeps for 10 seconds

       logs += line
    cluster_log = ClusterLog(cluster=cluster, log=logs)
    cluster_log.save()
    return cluster_log
```